# Avro with Kafka - Deserializing with changing schema

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

Based on Avro schema I generated a class (Data) to work with the class appropriate to the schema
After it I encode the data and send in to other application "A" using kafka

```
Data data; // <- The object was initialized before . Here it is only the declaration "for example"
EncoderFactory encoderFactory = EncoderFactory.get();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BinaryEncoder encoder = encoderFactory. directBinaryEncoder(out, null);                    
        DatumWriter<Tloog> writer;                  
        writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<Data>( Data.class);
        writer.write(data, encoder);
        byte[] avroByteMessage = out.toByteArray();
```

On the other side (in the application "A") I deserilize the the data by implementing Deserializer

```
class DataDeserializer implements Deserializer<Data> {
    private String encoding = "UTF8";

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        // nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public Tloog deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        try {
            if (data == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                        DatumReader<Tloog> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<Data>( Data.class);
                        DecoderFactory decoderFactory = DecoderFactory.get();
                        BinaryDecoder decoder = decoderFactory.binaryDecoder( data, null);
                        Data decoded = reader.read(null, decoder);
                        return decoded;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error when deserializing byte[] to string due to unsupported encoding " + encoding);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that this approach requires the use of SpecificDatumReader, I.e.the Data class should be integrated  with the application code...This could be problematic - schema could change and therefore Data class should be re-generated and integrated once more
2 questions:

1. Should I use GenericDatumReader in the application? How to do that
   correctly. (I can save the schema simply in the application)
2. Isthere a simple way to work with SpecificDatumReader if Data changes?       How could it be integrated with out much trouble?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `GenericDatumReader` -- well, actually I derive my reader class from it, but you get the point. To use it, I keep my schemas in a special Kafka topic -- `Schema` surprisingly enough. Consumers and producers both, on startup, read from this topic and configure their respective parsers.

If you do it like this, you can even have your consumers and producers update their schemas on the fly, without having to restart them. This was a design goal for me -- I didn't want to have to restart my applications in order to add or change schemas. Which is why `SpecificDatumReader` doesn't work for me, and honestly why I use `Avro` in the first place instead of something like `Thrift`.

**Update**

The normal way to do Avro is to store the schema in the file with the records. I don't do it that way, primarily because I can't. I use `Kafka`, so I can't store the schemas directly with the data -- I have to store the schemas in a separate topic.

The way I do it, first I load all of my schemas. You can read them from a text file; but like I said, I read them from a `Kafka` topic. After I read them from Kafka, I have an array like this:

```
val schemaArray: Array[String] = Array(
  """{"name":"MyObj","type":"record","fields":[...]}""",
  """{"name":"MyOtherObj","type":"record","fields":[...]}"""
)
```

Apologize for the `Scala` BTW, but it's what I got.

At any rate, then you need to create a parser, and foreach schema, parse it and create readers and writers, and save them off to Maps:

```
val parser = new Schema.Parser()
val schemas = Map(schemaArray.map{s => parser.parse(s)}.map(s => (s.getName, s)):_*)
val readers = schemas.map(s => (s._1, new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord](s._2)))
val writers = schemas.map(s => (s._1, new GenericDatumWriter[GenericRecord](s._2)))
var decoder: BinaryDecoder = null
```

I do all of that before I parse an actual record -- that's just to configure the parser. Then, to decode an individual record I would do:

```
val byteArray: Array[Byte] = ... // <-- Avro encoded record
val schemaName: String = ... // <-- name of the Avro schema

val reader = readers.get(schemaName).get

decoder = DecoderFactory.get.binaryDecoder(byteArray, decoder)
val record = reader.read(null, decoder)
```

Comment: Just to add this here [Confluent Schema Registry](http://docs.confluent.io/1.0.1/schema-registry/docs/index.html).

Comment: I looked at Schema Registry -- it seems very odd that you would smash a RESTful interface onto a Kafka back-ended architecture. Why not just let your clients interact directly with your Schema stream? It's like pulling a car chassis with a team of horses. Certainly for a use case like this, where we are already consuming Kafka streams, you don't want to now go make RESTful calls to pick up your Schemas.

Comment: I liked it for the automatic schema evolution and protection from data corruption. The fact that it only stores a reference to the schema and not the full schema with each data point is nice as well. Adding a web call to fetch the schemas hasn't been an issue for us.

Comment: @DavidGriffin Can yo add an example to your answer?As it not very clear to me.

Comment: Updates made. It's in Scala, but you should get the general idea.